# How to apply t-test on MATLAB?

Tags: t-test, matlab

I have accuracy vectors of two classifiers. How can I make a t-test for them on Matlab and is there a good plot type to show it?

Comment: Remember to check if those two vectors are normally distributed first.

Comment: If you want a more elaborate answer, it would help if you formulated the question a bit more in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ttest` function ([documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ttest.html)) if it's a paired t-test, or the `ttest2` function if it's not paired ([documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ttest2.html)). In either case, the function call is just `ttest(x,y)` or `ttest2(x,y)`. It returns at least a 0-1 indicator of whether the hypothesis is rejected or not, and can return the p-value and other things if you like.

As for plots, I'm not sure what you're looking for.